# Resets View when dismissing from JTSImageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with images. When i scroll down and select an image, Onclick of image i am using following library to make it zoomIn/ZoomOut/Panning etc. When i come back, the tableview again scroll back starting at 0 element. I am not using `didSelectRow` but a custom selector. Has anyone worked with this library before? I can post the code if required.

https://github.com/jaredsinclair/JTSImageViewController

Assigning Selector

```
    AsyncImageView *imageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 300.0f)];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [tapRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(bigButtonTapped:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Method Call

```
- (void)bigButtonTapped:(id)sender {

UIView *view = [sender view];
AsyncImageView *imageView1 = (AsyncImageView *)[view viewWithTag:IMAGE_VIEW_TAG];

// Create image info
JTSImageInfo *imageInfo = [[JTSImageInfo alloc] init];
#if TRY_AN_ANIMATED_GIF == 1

#else
imageInfo.image = imageView1.image;
#endif
imageInfo.referenceRect = imageView1.frame;
imageInfo.referenceView = imageView1.superview;
imageInfo.referenceContentMode = imageView1.contentMode;
imageInfo.referenceCornerRadius = imageView1.layer.cornerRadius;

// Setup view controller
JTSImageViewController *imageViewer = [[JTSImageViewController alloc]
                                       initWithImageInfo:imageInfo
                                       mode:JTSImageViewControllerMode_Image
                                       backgroundStyle:JTSImageViewControllerBackgroundOption_Blurred];

// Present the view controller.
[imageViewer showFromViewController:self transition:JTSImageViewControllerTransition_FromOriginalPosition];
}
```

Comment: Selector Code Added.

Comment: was your content scrollable? @ShahiM

Comment: No. my use case was just a static grid of 6 images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `JSTImageViewController` doesnt play nice with `UITableView` in `iOS8`. This issue has been reported in the `GitHub` page for `JSTImageViewController`. There's also a possible workaround mentioned :

> ...Apparently it's the default behaviour to reset the contentOffset after returning from a modal view controller...
>   ...setting the modal presentation style of JTSImageViewController to UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen fixes the issue (since it doesn't remove the hierarchy below it and retains the scroll position I think).

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"8.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) 
{
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
}
```

Read the full thread [**Here**](https://github.com/jaredsinclair/JTSImageViewController/issues/53)

Comment: Hmmm.. Thanx alot. It seems that is the issues. Ill check and get back.